# How to programmatically generate/get a link to Azure's Portal for a resource?

Tags: azure

Give a list of resources from Azure's Rest API via [Resources - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list). Is there a way I can reliability generate or fetch a link to the Azure Portal's (portal.azure.com) overview of that resource?

Comment: Do you have the tenant id of the subscription available to you?

Comment: Yes, I have the tenant id of the subscription available.

Comment: In our application, this is how we're creating the resource link to the portal: `<portal-url (https://portal.azure.com)>/#@<tenant-id (something.onmicrosoft.com or guid)>/resource/<resource-id (fetched from the API call)>`. Do let me know if this works and I will post this as answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri Ah nice, I didn't know I could use the GUID there and the portal would redirect. It does seem to be an answer, not sure if it works with every type of resource but I'm guessing it is the best option.

Comment: In our application, we tried with subscription, resource groups, storage accounts, cosmos db accounts, redis cache accounts, service bus accounts, and search accounts and for all of them it worked flawlessly. I will post my comment as an answer now.

Comment: [Yannis Stiakogiannakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15589054) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67016026) saying "This has been recently documented here: [https://github.com/Azure/portaldocs/blob/master/portal-sdk/generated/portalfx-links.md](https://github.com/Azure/portaldocs/blob/master/portal-sdk/generated/portalfx-links.md)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To deeplink a resource in the portal, here's the logic we're using to create the link:

```
[portal-url]/#@[tenant-id]/resource/[resource-id]
```

Where

`[portal-url]`: `https://portal.azure.com`

`[tenant-id]`: `something.onmicrosoft.com or tenant guid`

`[resource-id]`: `Id of the resource returned through resource list API call`

Comment: Thanks: https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/commit/9b88996cd025121f72963b4aaf00523b2a71ef71 :-)

Comment: Does Azure officially document this anywhere?

Comment: I haven't been able to find this documented by Azure anywhere. Does anyone know if this a stable means of generating links?